# Gravar dados no Firestore - promisse status pendente

Tags: firebase, firestore

Fala galera! Estou trabalhando em um projeto que preciso salvar alguns docs no firestore do Firebase, mas o código simplesmente para no execução e a promisse fica com status de pendente.
Ou seja, não grava nada e não da erro.

```
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { database } from "../../../firebase/firebase";

async function postFAC(){
 const refCollecttion = collection(database, "facs");
 await addDoc(refCollecttion, {
   autorFacEmail: autorFacEmail,
   textFac: textFac,
   respFAC:'',
   dataPergunta: `${dataHoje}`,
   dataResposta:'',
   id: `fac${length}`
 })
 .then(resp => console.log('docRef', resp))
 .catch(err=> console.log(err))
 .finally(end=> console.log('end', end))
}
```

As regras de segurança para gravar no db estão desbloqueadas.
Se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato. Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi aqui galera. O problema era no arquivo de config do firebase. As variáveis de ambiente não estavam funcionando corretamente para as funções de gravação, mas para consulta sim. Não sei porque disso, mas colocando os dados direto no arquivo (removendo as variáveis de ambiente) deu certo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).